# Do deeper Strata give more Crowns/Heat?

Tags: spiral-knights

In Spiral Knights I recently made it to Tier Two! This means I can adventure past the second stratum and into the third and fourth.

While I know that deeper strata means the possibilities for better *material* drops, do the deeper strata also reward, on average, more crowns and heat? I'm trying to decide if it's worth it to pay the fee to start deeper rather than adventure close to the surface and not "waste" any potential revenue getting to the lower depths in the first place.

Comment: I _overheard_ that Tier 2 gives you twice as much money, with Tier 3 giving somewhat less than that. Also, what's your ingame nick? I'm two transmutations away from making the jump myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, every tier of depth has more potential crowns and heat than the last. Mostly because of the more difficult monsters.

The even-numbered strata always give more crowns and heat than the odd-numbered strata - basically, once you reach the clockwork terminal (4, 13, or 20), the loot kicks into high gear (and goes back down when you return to an odd-numbered strata.

Comment: Is there any data on this, or is it simply from personal observation?

Comment: Pretty much observation, but also everything I have read on the official forums.